# Problems in Python with difference between import module and from module import

Tags: python, python-import

I have had a problem with the difference between `import module` and `from module import name1, name2 ...` in Python. I am a newcomer (last week) to Python, using Python 3.6 on Windows-64.

In the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules) there is a short discussion of these two `import` approaches. It is stated that `from module import *` is not recommended because of the danger of polluting the current namespace. However, there is no indication that there is any material operational difference between `import module` and `from module import name1, name2..`, with the implication that this is a matter of preference or convenience.

However, there seems to be a big difference in practice. Consider this module named ModuleA, defining a global variable and a function:

```
# ModuleA
iGlobalA = 0

def fA():
    iGlobalA += 1
    print( "MA: iGlobalA=", iGlobalA )

print( "Module A Initialised, iGlobalA=", iGlobalA )
```

Using `import ModuleA` creates a separate `ModuleA` namespace. Now the members of that module are available as public members of the namespace, like this:

```
import ModuleA as MA

def fX():
    print( "MX: Before, ModuleA.iGlobalA=", MA.iGlobalA )
    MA.fA()
    print( "MX: After 1, ModuleA.iGlobalA=", MA.iGlobalA )
    MA.fA()
    print( "MX: After 2, ModuleA.iGlobalA=", MA.iGlobalA )

fX()
```

This is the output:

```
MA: Initialised, iGlobalA= 100
MX: Before, ModuleA.iGlobalA= 100
MA: iGlobalA incremented to 101
MX: After 1, ModuleA.iGlobalA= 101
MA: iGlobalA incremented to 102
MX: After 2, ModuleA.iGlobalA= 102
```

which is exactly as expected. Contrast this with ModuleY which uses the form `from ModuleA import fA, iGlobalA` and then refers to these members of ModuleA without qualification:

```
# ModuleY
from ModuleA import fA, iGlobalA   

def fY():
    print( "MY: Before, ModuleA.iGlobalA=", iGlobalA )
    fA()
    print( "MY: After 1, ModuleA.iGlobalA=", iGlobalA )
    fA()
    print( "MY: After 2, ModuleA.iGlobalA=", iGlobalA )

fY()
```

In this case the output is:

```
MA: Initialised, iGlobalA= 100
MY: Before, ModuleA.iGlobalA= 100
MA: iGlobalA incremented to 101
MY: After 1, ModuleA.iGlobalA= 100
MA: iGlobalA incremented to 102
MY: After 2, ModuleA.iGlobalA= 100
```

In this case the global variable `iGlobalA` is imported *as a copy from ModuleA* after ModuleA is initialised, and becomes a completely separate variable from `ModuleA.iGlobalA`. It is also true that function `fA` is imported as a reference to the function in ModuleA *as defined at the time of import* - if the function is reassigned at some later point within ModuleA, then the reference to `fA()` in the importing module remains unchanged, pointing only to the function as originally imported.

I would have thought these differences between these import syntaxes should be more clearly stated in the documentation. It also means that someone designing a library module needs to specify how that module should be imported.

Edit - after comment by @abdullah-ahmed-ghaznavi
These are my questions

- Did I miss something in the documentation?
- Is this behaviour the same across all platforms?
- Is this the intended behaviour that can be relied upon in future?

Comment: _"someone designing a library module needs to specify how that module should be imported"_ That's not really true. That person should just avoid using global variables or redefining methods. With any well-written module, it doesn't matter if you use `import module` or `from module import whatever`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey - fair enough, so I guess the corollary would be that anyone designing a library should be aware of the implications of these differences and ensure that the importer can use either import syntax.

Comment: Well nice explanation, ***but what you want from this question ?*** do you only want to discuss that the library writer/programmer  must state the import statement in there documentation ? and i am agree with @Aran-Fey

Comment: @abdullah-ahmed-ghaznavi - Sorry, that's true, I hit the problem then found out the answer - but I have added some actual questions in my edit..

Comment: Python modules are namespaces. When you use `from module mod import func` or whatever, that is equivalent to `import mod; func = mod.func; del mod`. The rest of the behavior you are seeing stems from the documented semantics of Python assignment. You can read a good summary [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: @JohnRC you may want to choose another answer (or none FWIW - I'm not asking you to select mine instead) - because the one you accepted is actually partly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case the global variable iGlobalA is imported as a copy from ModuleA

Nope. Just after `from ModuleA import iGlobalA`, both `ModuleA.iGlobalA` and `ModuleY.iGlobalA` point to the very same object - you can check this by printing `id(iGlobalA)` in both modules. Now while both names (initially) point to the same object, the *names* themselves are distinct - they live in different namespaces (one in `ModuleA` and the other in `ModuleY`), so when `fA()` rebinds the name `iGlobalA` - which is really `ModuleA.iGlobalA` - only the name leaving in `ModuleA` is impacted (so at this point both names point to different objects).

On the other hand when in `ModuleY` you use the qualified name `ModuleA.iGlobalA`, you only have one single name, so when this name is rebound (in `ModuleA`) by `fA()` you see the change in `ModuleY`, because you are really checking the same *name*.

Note that if instead of rebiding a name you had tried the same thing with mutating a mutable object (ie appending to a list, updating a dict etc) you wouldn't have noticed any difference in behaviour:

```
# ModuleA
iGlobalA = []

def fA():
    iGlobalA.append(1)
    print( "MA: iGlobalA=", iGlobalA )

print( "Module A Initialised, iGlobalA=", iGlobalA )
```

What you need to understand here is mainly [what Python "variables" really are](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), and also that Python has no real global namespace ("global" really means "module level").

> I would have thought these differences between these import syntaxes should be more clearly stated in the documentation.

Possibly yes. Note that there actually some documentation about the whole thing, cf https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import and https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html, but you do indeed have to understand what "defines a name in the local namespace" and "a reference to that value is stored in the local namespace" really imply.

> It also means that someone designing a library module needs to specify how that module should be imported.

The problem here is either that the lib is badly designed (and if it uses globals that way it *is* badly designed indeed) or (at least) that the name you tried to access is not (or should not be) part of the lib's API.

> Did I miss something in the documentation?

Possibly too, I'm afraid I'm far too used to how this work to remember how I first learned it

> Is this behaviour the same across all platforms?
>   Is this the intended behaviour that can be relied upon in future?

Yes and yes. This is part of the language's specifications actually and changing it would break almost all existing code.

Comment: I am embarrased that I never took the opportunity to express my thanks for your answers to my questions - I really appreciated the time you took to consider the questions and answer them so clearly. Many thanks! It was a great help and pushed my understanding of Python forwards in a single leap that might otherwise have taken a lot of trial and error.